# Ionic 2 back leads to blank screen with no errors in console

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Whether I use `navCtrl.pop()` in class or `navPop` in template, doesn't matter. Whenever any of the two instructions gets executed, the screen becomes white-blank. No errors on console what-so-ever.

I tried Google search, but all the retrieved forum posts suggest either `app-scripts` old version or ionic 2 old version. However, I updated anything that is possible. My current configurations are as follows.

```
 $ionic info
 Your system information:

 Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
 Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
 ios-deploy version: Not installed
 ios-sim version: Not installed
 OS: Linux 3.16
 Node Version: v6.7.0
 Xcode version: Not installed
```

packages.json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {


    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",

    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.8.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "githubIonic: An Ionic project"
}
```

Update:

I get the navCtrl using the following instruction

```
import {  App } from 'ionic-angular';
.
.
constructor( private app: App) {
  this.navCtrl = app.getActiveNav();

}
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `navCtrl.pop()` and not `router.pop()`

Comment: @Huzaib Which back are you talking about phone's or app's back button? Make sure you are pushing the page into the stack before poping it up.

Comment: question updated